# While import/Export attributes get 500 internal server error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, product-attribute, importexport, .htaccess

I am working on magento-1.9.2.1. I want to import and export attributes. for this, When I goto

```
system ->import/export ->attributes ->import or export.
```

I got following Internal server error.

> ### 500 internal server error while import/Export attributes

Comment: which version of Magento ? Do you use module to import attribute ? Because in magento 1.9.x, import/export attributes are not in default

Comment: See logs (apache or nginx)... Or magento log into magento folder /var/log/. You can see errors

Comment: go to system > Configuration > developper and active log into log section. Retry import and wait the 500 error. And go to /var/log and look sytem.log and report/ folder if you have. File permission 0777 are not a good idea... Look at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Because this menu item does not exist in Magento 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information really. As @Imaginaerum mentioned, there is no import/export feature for attributes in standard Magento CE 1.9.2.1 so you must be using an extension. Without telling us which one, there's no way we can give you specific help.

That said, one golden rule that will help you with this sort of error: If you're getting a non-Magento-branded error page such as "Internal Server Error" then it's an error Magento has failed to catch and the error message will be in your web server log file (e.g. /var/log/nginx/error.log or /var/log/apache2/error_log), not in Magento's log files.